# Finding hash match aggregate

Tags: sql-server, execution-plan, aggregate, performance, performance-tuning

After reading following blogs, I understand that `hash match` aggregate causes `blocking`. Using appropriate indexes it can be made as `stream aggregate`.

1. [Blocking/non-blocking aggregate operators](https://sqlsunday.com/2014/06/15/blocking-aggregate-operators/)
2. [The blocking nature of aggregates - Rob Farley](http://sqlblog.com/blogs/rob_farley/archive/2011/03/08/the-blocking-nature-of-aggregates.aspx)
3. [Hash Aggregate-Craig Freedman](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/craigfr/2006/09/20/hash-aggregate/)

I have a database that has over 200 tables which has been created years back. I am trying to find all queries with group by that is currently working with `hash match` aggregate operator. One possibility I found is using dmv like below. But I don't know how to filter it to list only queries with `hash match` aggregate operators. How to achieve this? Also, on a big picture level, what are the other options to get this information other than following dmv?

```
SELECT cp.objtype AS ObjectType,
    OBJECT_NAME(st.objectid,st.dbid) AS ObjectName,
    cp.usecounts AS ExecutionCount,
    st.TEXT AS QueryText,
    qp.query_plan AS QueryPlan
FROM sys.dm_exec_cached_plans AS cp
CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_query_plan(cp.plan_handle) AS qp
CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_sql_text(cp.plan_handle) AS st
WHERE st.TEXT LIKE '%GROUP%'
```

Comment: I don't know that it's worthwhile to do this . Blocking operators will stop the first row appearing quickly, but are not necessarily bad.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is not possible to *directly* connect part of the query text (e.g. `GROUP BY`) with a specific operation in the final execution plan.

You *can* write a query to find plans that:

- Contain a Hash Match Aggregate; and
- The query text contains a `GROUP BY` clause

...which is not quite the same thing, since this will find plans where the grouping logic was implemented using a Stream Aggregate, replaced with another operation, or even removed entirely - but happens to also contain a Hash Match Aggregate for some other reason.

For example:

```
WITH XMLNAMESPACES
(
    DEFAULT 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2004/07/showplan'
)
SELECT
    DECP.cacheobjtype,
    DECP.objtype,
    DECP.plan_handle,
    DEQP.objectid,
    DEQP.query_plan,
    DEST.[text]
FROM sys.dm_exec_cached_plans AS DECP
CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_query_plan(DECP.plan_handle) AS DEQP
CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_sql_text(DECP.plan_handle) AS DEST
WHERE
    1 = DEQP.query_plan.exist(
        '//RelOp[
            @PhysicalOp = "Hash Match"
            and @LogicalOp = ("Aggregate","Partial Aggregate","Flow Distinct")]')
    AND DEST.[text] LIKE N'%GROUP BY%';
```

This might miss some `GROUP BY` queries if they have a different amount (or type) of white space between `GROUP` and `BY` than expected by the query. Maybe replacing all white space with spaces and collapsing contiguous ones into a single space could be done before the `LIKE` or use SQLCLR and regex instead.

You would need to inspect the results by hand to determine if the Hash Match Aggregate correlates directly to the `GROUP BY` clause or not. The query above could be extended, perhaps, to check the plan *HashKeysBuild* element against the grouping columns, but this would be hard to get right, due to optimizer operations.